What is the time complexity of a function f(n) that is O(g(n)) where "part" of g(n) is o(h(n))?
This is in the context of graph algorithms, so I'll refer to V as the set of vertices in the graph and E as the set of edges in the graph (i.e., the input is a graph G = (V, E)). Let's say a graph algorithm is in O(ELgV) and I know that E is in o((V^2)/LgV), what would the overall time complexity of the algorithm be in terms of little o (is this even a meaningful question)?

How does  relate to  or ?

I've edited the question to clarify

f(n) =O(ELgV) and  E is in o((V^2)/LgV) which means that   f(n) =O(o((V^2)/LgV)*LgV) then f(n) =o(V^2)
